# How to use bootstrap modal for multiple controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use same modal window with different parent controller, the only difference in modal controller is separate factories that i am calling  e.g `Ctrl-1-Factory.getServerFiles` so similarly i want to call `Ctrl-2-Factory` when modal populated for `Ctrl2`.

ModalCtrl.js

```
angular.module('App').controller('ServerFilesCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, FileSaver, $uibModalInstance, Ctrl-1-Factory, $uibModal) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
    Ctrl-1-Factory.getServerFiles().then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
});
```

Ctrl-1.js

```
 $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         templateUrl: '/web/global/modal.html',
            controller:'ModalController'
         });
```

Ctrl-2.js

```
 $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         templateUrl: '/web/global/modal.html',
            controller:'ModalController'
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a  service method.

```
angular.module('App').factory('FilesModal', function() {
  return {
    openModal: openModal
  };

  function openModal() {
    return $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: '/web/global/modal.html',
      controller: 'ModalController'
    });
  }
});

angular.module('App').controller('Ctrl1', function(FilesModal) {
  $scope.someEventFunction = someEventFunction;

  function someEventFunction() {
    $scope.modalInstance = FilesModal.openModal();
  }
});
```

Pass in arguments as needed to make it more robust

Comment: I want to use different events from Modal controller , in your answer someEventFunction are in parent controller.

Comment: need to be more specific. Not entirely clear what you are wanting to do

Comment: As i mentioned in my question i want to use same modal for different states or controllers because data is different so i want to populate data from different factories for the same modal.

Comment: you can always use a `resolve` in `$uibModal.open()` and pass an argument to the factory method i showed you to set up that resolve